# How to add Array as a property in ADO .NET Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

I am using Custom data service provider for an application.

I need to add following class as entity

```
public class PhysicalAddress
{
  public PhysicalAddress();

  public string City { get; set; }
  public string Country { get; set; }
  public string CountryCode { get; set; }
}

class Parent
{
  public PhysicalAddress[] Address { get; set; }
}

class Child : Parent
{
  string division;
  string business;
}
```

Here Adress property is array of PhysicalAddress class. How can I define and add it as a primitive type  in the Child entity type?

Thanks,

Ram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using navigational properties I able to do this.